# MVC4 ViewModel - Add data to 2 tables in one transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm using MVC 4 and Entity Framework for a project. When I want to create a Product which is composed of a ProductType (a product type is composed himself of a ProductCompany). So I have 3 tables (in fact 2, because the product company table is only used to choose a company) and what I want to do is to add a product AND a product type in one go, by a Create Product form".

I read that I have to use the ViewModel technology but I have no idea about it, if it would meet my needs.

Any help to do that? If something's not clear, please feel free to say it.

Comment: It sounds like you're tying the idea of View Model too tightly to the data in this case. You can have a view model that is a hybrid of data intended for two or three tables and when you go to save the data to the database, you can do separate inserts.

Comment: So should I use a viewmodel in this case? Or just create a "hybrid view"?

Comment: Hopefully, I'll get the terms right here. A View Model, as I understand it, is a data model for a view. If you're using EF, EF creates a class, like Product, that can directly correspond to a Products table in a database. The EF part of your project is the Model (not necessarily the View Model). So, you can have a View that has your form. When the form posts, the form data can be captured in a C# class object. That View Model object's properties can be used to create one or more EF objects and they, in turn, can be written to the database.

Comment: To be honest, you need to be more specific in your question.  Personally I think this question shows a serious lack of research into what you are talking about.  Perhaps if you think about the specific problem you are trying to solve and actual tech you are using - for example, bar stating "MVC4" there is no C# example code.  Example code of what you are trying to do will help people give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "ViewModel technology". A view model is just a pattern. The idea is that instead of directly passing the view your entity, which usually has more data on it than you need in your view and simultaneously lacks certain data you may need in your view, you create a "view model", which is just another POCO that has just the data you need for your view. You fill the view model's data from your entity, but it doesn't have to have all the same fields as your entity, and will usually have additional fields that don't make sense on your entity, such as a `SelectList` to use with a `DropDownFor`.